# Passing _id to pubsub Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to only publish documents whose field attribute is `this.params._id`, but when I implement the code below, I see the object created flash on the screen then disappear (and never hit the collection).  Id like to publish the following:

```
 Meteor.publish('details', function(parentId){
     return detailsCollection.find({parentId: parentId});
 });
```

While the client subscribe passes the appropriate argument for the publish method:

```
 waitOn: function(){
         return Meteor.subscribe('details', this.params._id);
     }
```

Comment: parentId its an actual field into the detailsCollection? or its the _id of the document?

Comment: i figured it out.  It was a typo